# What is different between props and vars object in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

Im new in load and performance testing so could anyone explain me, what is difference between vars object and props object in JMeter beanshell script.

Im also bit confuse about  JMeter variable and properties.

Thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The most simplest explanation would be that variables(vars) are not shared between threads, and properties(props) ARE shared.

Usage:

> vars - ( JMeterVariables) - gives read/write access to variables:
>
> - vars.get(key);
> - vars.put(key,val);
> - vars.putObject("OBJ1",new Object());
> - vars.getObject("OBJ2");
>
> props - (JMeterProperties - class java.util.Properties):
>
> - props.get("START.HMS");
> - props.put("PROP1","1234");

You can refer to [this](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#properties) link to get more info on vars and props.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

As per [Blazemeter Blog](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell)

**vars**

> vars (JMeter variables) is the most frequently used component. It’s an
>   instance of the `org.apache.jmeter.threads`.JMeterVariables class and
>   provides read/write access to current variables, is capable of
>   enumerating/changing existing variables, creating new ones, and
>   obtaining nested properties.  All JMeter variables are Java strings.
>   If you need to put something else to a JMeter variable, you’ll need to
>   cast it to the string first. The following code snippet demonstrates
>   how to save previous sampler response data into a JMeter variable.
>
> ```
> byte [] samplerdata = ctx.getPreviousResult().getResponseData();
> String samplerdatastring = new String(samplerdata);
> vars.put("samplerdata",samplerdatastring);
> ```

**props**

> Basically, this is the same as “vars,” but it exposes JMeter
>   properties instead. See JavaDoc on java.util.Properties and JMeter
>   documentation on JMeter properties for more information. The primary
>   distinction between props and vars is that props have a “global”
>   scope, whereas the scope of “vars” is limited to the current thread
>   group.

Refer to this [link](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#properties).